# DigitalOcean Deploy - "ImportError: No module named flask.ext.wtf"

Tags: apache, flask

All, I'm trying to deploy a simple page using flask/apache on a digitalocean server. It all works fine locally, but not on the server.

`__init__.py` contains the statement:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form,TextField
```

`try_me.wsgi` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/try_me/")

from try_me import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

Getting the following error (from `/var/log/apache2/error.log`):

```
[Mon Jul 29 14:16:50 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Mon Jul 29 14:16:50 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Mon Jul 29 14:16:50 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 29 14:16:57 2013] [error] [client 74.66.8.166] mod_wsgi (pid=2920): Target WSGI script '/var/www/try_me/try_me.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Jul 29 14:16:57 2013] [error] [client 74.66.8.166] mod_wsgi (pid=2920): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/try_me/try_me.wsgi'.
[Mon Jul 29 14:16:57 2013] [error] [client 74.66.8.166] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jul 29 14:16:57 2013] [error] [client 74.66.8.166]   File "/var/www/try_me/try_me.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Mon Jul 29 14:16:57 2013] [error] [client 74.66.8.166]     from try_me import app as application
[Mon Jul 29 14:16:57 2013] [error] [client 74.66.8.166]   File "/var/www/try_me/try_me/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[Mon Jul 29 14:16:57 2013] [error] [client 74.66.8.166]     from flask.ext.wtf import Form
[Mon Jul 29 14:16:57 2013] [error] [client 74.66.8.166]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 87, in load_module
[Mon Jul 29 14:16:57 2013] [error] [client 74.66.8.166]     raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
[Mon Jul 29 14:16:57 2013] [error] [client 74.66.8.166] ImportError: No module named flask.ext.wtf
```

I was able to import manually in a python interpreter (under virtualenv):

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 16:53:07) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from flask.ext.wtf import Form
>>> Form
<class 'flask_wtf.form.Form'>
```

Any ideas on how to proceed here?

Comment: What does your `try_me.wsgi` file look like?

Comment: added to original post.

Comment: Have you got your virtualenv's site-packages folder into PATH in the wsgi script? Check [this blog post](http://bucksnort.pennington.net/blog/post/deploy-flask-mod_wsgi_virtenv/) on Flask + virtualenv + mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION (Following Cathy's advice above, and dAnjou below), virtualenv must be activated from the wsgi script. Adding activate_this execution solved the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
activate_this = '/var/www/try_me/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
import sys
..
```

Comment: Wrong. Or at least not the optimal way. Like the [official documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/#working-with-virtual-environments) (click that) says, you should activate your virtualenv in your WSGI file.