# How to resolve a NameError: global name 'ContactForm' is not defined

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I create a contact form in Flask, but it's not working. It gives the error NameError: global name 'ContactForm' is not defined

The custom form is :

```
<form action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" method=post>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

    {{ form.name.label }}
    {{ form.name }}

    {{ form.email.label }}
    {{ form.email }}

    {{ form.subject.label }}
    {{ form.subject }}

    {{ form.message.label }}
    {{ form.message }}

    {{ form.submit }}
  </form>
```

routes.py is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from forms import ContactForm
app = Flask(__name__)     

def contact():
    form = ContactForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        return 'Form posted.'

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

How may I resolve the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926869/digitalocean-deploy-importerror-no-module-named-flask-ext-wtf ?

Comment: @Brar: "Cannot import XXX" is a pretty common Python error message that typically has nothing to do with your code, but instead the fact that your environment is not set up correctly (in other words, you have not correctly installed a package, or you installed it in the wrong place). Do you have Flask-WTF installed correctly?

Comment: please guys anyone give another solution for solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file called forms.py and insert the below code in there.  Then your code should work.

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form

from wtforms import TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField, validators


class ContactForm(Form):
    name = TextField("Name", [validators.Required()])
    email = TextField("Email", [validators.Required(), validators.email()])
    subject = TextField("Subject", [validators.Required()])
    message = TextAreaField("Message", [validators.Required()])
    submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly , do you have flask-wtf installed ?
and try this :    `form = ContactForm(request.form)`